# Android: Is it possible to change the color of icons in status bar in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, colors, window, icons, statusbar

I have the following function that changes the color of the status bar:

```
   public static void colorStatusBar(Window window, Context context, boolean transparent) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        if(transparent){
            window.setStatusBarColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        }else{
            window.setStatusBarColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.timeline_unselected));
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is, it changes the status bar color, but not the icons color, which makes them nearly invisible.
Example: http://postimg.org/image/ah01hzxdz/
Is it possible to change the icons colour too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible to change it to gray (no custom colors) but this only works from API 23 and above you only need to add this in your values-v23/styles.xml into your theme declaration.

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Answer (score 3):

Not since Lollipop. Starting with Android 5.0, the guidelines say:

Notification icons must be entirely white.
Even if they're not, the system will only consider the alpha channel of your icon, rendering them white

The only way to have a coloured icon on Lollipop is to lower your targetSdkVersion to values <21.

If you still however decide you want colored icons, you could use the DrawableCompat.setTint method from the new v4 support library.

Comment: What if I have a targetSdkVersion lower than 21 and I want to make my blue icon turn to white. Do I need to get a white icon or can I set the tint somehow in the notification builder?